# ping cron job does not work in cron schedule, but does as command line

Tags: centos, files, cron

I have this cron scheduled:

```
0 * * * * ping -D -O -c 3492 8.8.8.8 | grep received > /home/user/.direc/packet_drops.txt
```

The command works fine when run manually and exports to the .txt file fine after the ping completes.

When run in the cron, the file remains empty. I have tried the manual command and the cron under the same user, same issue.

What am I missing? I've tried redirecting error output too, and it still remains empty.

Comment: Add full path of ping+grep commands ?

Comment: Have you checked your logs? Not sure about where to look on your system; possibly `/var/log/cron` or, if it's a systemd-based version, via `journalctl`.

Comment: @fra-san The log just says: `May 17 23:00:01 localhost CROND[6755]: (user) CMD (ping -D -O -c 3492 8.8.8.8 | grep received > /home/user/.direc/packet_drops.txt)`

Comment: AFAIK (possibly not always true, depending on `cron`'s implementation) both permission (related to writing to a file) and binary-not-found errors should be logged. If we rule them out, a wild guess could be that, when you look at the file, the _current_ job execution has already truncated it (it happens as soon as the job starts). You should be able to check this by appending (`>>`) to `packet_drops.txt`, instead of truncating (`>`) it.

Comment: @fra-san That seems to be it. It's appending now. I'll just need to figure out a way to clear the file before each write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments to your question, the likely reason your `/home/user/.direc/packet_drops.txt` file was empty when you looked at it is because it had already been truncated by the next execution of your cron job.

The pipeline is set up as soon as the job starts, and redirection is performed as part of that initial setup. `ping` is started every one hour and runs for 3492 seconds, thus giving you just a (theoretical) 108 seconds hourly window for reading `packet_drops.txt` before it gets truncated.

A way to only have a log file overwritten when a long-running job terminates (as you seemed to ask for in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587294/ping-cron-job-does-not-work-in-cron-schedule-but-does-as-command-line?noredirect=1#comment1094527_587294)) is to print its output to a temporary file and replace the destination file when the job ends.

It is easier to manage it as a `script`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

trap 'rm -f -- "$tmpfile"' EXIT
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
ping -D -O -c 3492 8.8.8.8 | grep received >"$tmpfile"
cat -- "$tmpfile" >/home/user/.direc/packet_drops.txt
```

and define a simpler cron job (it has less ways to fail and is thus easier to debug):

```
0 * * * * /path/to/script
```

Alternatively, to keep the brevity of a one-liner, you may leverage `awk`'s ability to manipulate files:

```
ping -D -O -c 3492 8.8.8.8 | awk -v file=/h..s.txt '/received/ { print >file }'
```

(File name shortened only for readability of this code block).

This AWK script still truncates the output file, but it only does it when a line matching `received` is found in the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Crontabs have a minimal set of environment variables. It is possible that the cronjob can't find the ping or grep command. You can check your environment variables in a cronjob with a simple command:

```
* * * * * env &> /tmp/cron-env.txt
```

Wait until this job run once and remove it again. Search in the output for the PATH variable and check if the path for the ping and grep command is contained.

You can find the path for these commands with:

```
whereis <command>
```

If they are not included you can add PATH variables to your cronjob:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:
* * * * * some-cron-job
```

Comment: Ping is in `/usr/bin` for me, and the environmental variables does contain that. I verified it with your cron test.

Comment: @Zeno did you tried to add `/usr/bin` to you PATH variable in the conrojob?